# how to reference a file in another branch

Tags: linux, bash, git, continuous-integration

I have a command to check a version in api.yaml file

```
yq eval-all '[.info.version] | .[0] == .[1]' api.yaml api.yaml
```

what I want from this command is, that second api.yaml file is referencing to api.yaml file in master branch

what should it be in a place of second api.yaml

Comment: There are no files in git branches, only content. You could, however,get the contents of the blob you need through `git show master:api.yaml`

Comment: Bash trick: `yq eval-all … api.yaml <(git show master:api.yaml)` See **Process Substitution** in [man bash](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution)